# no such column error, but I made the column

Tags: java, android-sqlite

I'm having trouble with a no such column error breaking my application. I'm making an app the holds pet information so later I can have the user select what they are looking for in a pet and then see the pet's details. That this point I'm just trying to see all the pets and their information, but every time I run the debugg I get the no such column petName. I made sure I have the column made and it looks the same as all the other columns. I'm trying to find out if this is due to the column or if it is something else I'm missing.

DBHelper

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

public static final String DBNAME = "PetAdoption.db";
public static final int DBVERSION = 1;

private static String[] testdata1 = new String[]{"Dog","Hound Mix","Creek","young","low","male","false","false","false"};
private static String[] testdata2 = new String[]{"Dog","Lab Mix","Marleigh","young","high","female","false","false","false"};
private static String[] testdata3 = new String[]{"Dog","Lab Mix","Carly","old","low","female","false","false","true"};
private static String[] testdata4 = new String[]{"Dog","Terrier Mix","Cruiser","young","low","male","true","true","false"};
private static String[] testdata5 = new String[]{"Cat","Domestic Shorthair","Floyd","young","low","male","false","true","false"};
private static String[] testdata6 = new String[]{"Cat","American Shorthair","Nevaeh","mature","low","female","true","true","true"};
private static String[] testdata7 = new String[]{"Cat","Domestic Longhair","Tiger","senior","high","female","false","false","false"};
private static String[] testdata8 = new String[]{"Cat","Norwegian Forest","Muke","senior","high","male","false","false","false"};

public DBHelper(Context context) {
    super(context,DBNAME,null,DBVERSION);
}

/* ADDED to simulate getting data from asset */
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS pet (" +
            BaseColumns._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY" +
            "," + "type TEXT" +
            "," + "breed TEXT" +
            "," + "petName TEXT" +
            "," + "lifestage TEXT" +
            "," + "energy TEXT" +
            "," + "gender TEXT" +
            "," + "kids TEXT" +
            "," + "dogs TEXT" +
            "," + "cats TEXT" +
            ")"
    );
    insertTestData(sqLiteDatabase,testdata1);
    insertTestData(sqLiteDatabase,testdata2);
    insertTestData(sqLiteDatabase,testdata3);
    insertTestData(sqLiteDatabase,testdata4);
    insertTestData(sqLiteDatabase,testdata5);
    insertTestData(sqLiteDatabase,testdata6);
    insertTestData(sqLiteDatabase,testdata7);
    insertTestData(sqLiteDatabase,testdata8);

}

private void insertTestData(SQLiteDatabase db, String[] data) {
    if (data.length != 8) return;
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put("type",data[0]);
    cv.put("breed",data[1]);
    cv.put("petName",data[2]);
    cv.put("lifestage",data[3]);
    cv.put("gender",data[4]);
    cv.put("kids",data[5]);
    cv.put("dogs",data[6]);
    cv.put("cats",data[7]);
    db.insert("pet",null,cv);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {
}
```

}

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private String typeSelection = "dog";
private String breedSelection = "alsatian";
private String petNameSelection = "creek";
private String lifeStageSelection = "young";
private String energySelection = "low";
private String genderSelection = "male";
private String kidsSelection = "false";
private String dogsSelection = "false";
private String catsSelection = "false";


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(
            getSelection(typeSelection,breedSelection,petNameSelection,lifeStageSelection,energySelection,genderSelection,kidsSelection,dogsSelection,catsSelection)
    );
    DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(
            getSelection("Dog",null, null,null,null, null, null, null, null)
    );
    DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(
            getSelection("Cat",null,null,null,null, null,null, null, null)
    );
    DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(
            getSelection(null,null,null,null,null, null, null, null, null)
    );
}

private Cursor getSelection(String type, String breed, String petName, String lifeStage, String energy, String gender, String kids, String dogs, String cats ) {
    String[] args = null;
    ArrayList<String> argsArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    StringBuilder whereClause = new StringBuilder();
    if (type != null && type.length() > 0) {
        if (whereClause.length() < 1) whereClause.append(" ");
        else whereClause.append(" AND ");
        whereClause.append(" type=?");
        argsArrayList.add(type);
    }
    if (breed != null && breed.length() > 0) {
        if (whereClause.length() < 1) whereClause.append(" ");
        else whereClause.append(" AND ");
        whereClause.append(" breed=?");
        argsArrayList.add(breed);
    }
    if (petName != null && petName.length() > 0) {
        if (whereClause.length() < 1) whereClause.append(" ");
        else whereClause.append(" AND ");
        whereClause.append(" petName=?");
        argsArrayList.add(petName);
    }
    if (lifeStage != null && type.length() > 0) {
        if (whereClause.length() < 1) whereClause.append(" ");
        else whereClause.append(" AND ");
        whereClause.append(" lifestage=?");
        argsArrayList.add(lifeStage);
    }
    if (energy != null && energy.length() > 0) {
        if (whereClause.length() < 1) whereClause.append(" ");
        else whereClause.append(" AND ");
        whereClause.append(" energy=?");
        argsArrayList.add(energy);
    }
    if (gender != null && gender.length() > 0) {
        if (whereClause.length() < 1) whereClause.append(" ");
        else whereClause.append(" AND ");
        whereClause.append(" gender=?");
        argsArrayList.add(gender);
    }
    if (kids != null && kids.length() > 0) {
        if (whereClause.length() < 1) whereClause.append(" ");
        else whereClause.append(" AND ");
        whereClause.append(" kids=?");
        argsArrayList.add(kids);
    }
    if (dogs != null && dogs.length() > 0) {
        if (whereClause.length() < 1) whereClause.append(" ");
        else whereClause.append(" AND ");
        whereClause.append(" dogs=?");
        argsArrayList.add(dogs);
    }
    if (cats != null && cats.length() > 0) {
        if (whereClause.length() < 1) whereClause.append(" ");
        else whereClause.append(" AND ");
        whereClause.append(" cats=?");
        argsArrayList.add(cats);
    }
    if (whereClause.length() > 1) {
        args = new String[argsArrayList.size()];
        int i = 0;
        for (String s: argsArrayList) {
            args[i++] = s;
        }
    }
    return DatabaseAccess.getInstance(this).getWritableDatabase().query("pet",null,whereClause.toString(),args,null,null,null);
}
```

}

Any help or suggestions is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I made sure I have the column made and it looks the same as all the other columns. I'm trying to find out if this is due to the column or if it is something else I'm missing.

One of the most frequent causes of a column not found is that the column has been added after running the app. This is because of confusion with when the onCreate method of the class that extends the SQLiteOpenHelper class runs.

Unlike an activity's onCreate method, which will run whenever the activity is started, **the SQLiteOpenHelper's onCreate method is only run when the database is created**. This will typically be once for the lifetime of the application. This adding a new column to the create table SQL will not add the new column.

To circumvent this issue, when developing the App, to introduce a new column is to uninstall the App and then rerun the App. However as this deletes the database any existing data will be lost (as you insert data in the onCreate method, uninstalling the app and then rerunning the App will probably be all that you need)

If retention of existing data is required, then the typical way is to introduce a new version by increasing the version number (DBVERSION in your case) and having suitable code to add the new column in the onUpdate method that makes the changes whilst retaining the existing data.